# Storing multiple selections from checkboxes in variables in HTML and display them

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am pretty new in HTML and Javascript. As part of an assignment, I have to make multiple web pages.
One of my web pages contains checkboxes, from where a user can choose multiple options.

```
    <form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="3 Point Scorer" id="skill">3 Point Scorer<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Defender" id="skill">Defender<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Rim Protector" id="skill">Rim Protector<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Attacker" id="skill">Attacker<br>

</form>
```

Now, if the user selects, say the first two options, is it possible to store those two options in a variable that I can use on the next page? Also, I would like to display the two options chosen in the current page.

For reference, the code for the concerned page is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NBA Position Selection</title>

  </head>
<!--<style>
body {
  background-image: url('Img3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
-->

  <body style="background-color:powderblue;">




    <h1>NBA Draft Prediction</h1>
<br>
      <a href="default.asp">
<img src="https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/5-anatomy-of-a-basketball-player-sebastian-kaulitzkiscience-photo-library.jpg" alt="Daruis Garland" style="float:centre;width:300px;height:300px;" align="middle">
         </a>
<br>
<br>

<script>
window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("Variables"));
</script>


    <script>
function random()
{
var a=document.getElementById("Attribute").value;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=a;
}
</script>

<br>
<h2> Choose the required Skills</h2>

<form method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="3 Point Scorer" id="skill">3 Point Scorer<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Defender" id="skill">Defender<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Rim Protector" id="skill">Rim Protector<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Attacker" id="skill">Attacker<br>

</form>

<br>
<br>
You have Chosen the skills of: <!..I want to display the chosen elements here..>

<div id="output"></div>


<br><br>
<a href="NBA_3rd_Page.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Click Here For Prediction</a>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is some kind of storage, you have some options that you can do a research and choose the best fit for you: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or a database (this one is more advanced and needs some back-end language not only simple JS)

Comment: @CalvinNunes why not just do a form submission and have the data passed as query string parameter?

Comment: ah yes, of course! Forgot this possibility, Thanks

Comment: @user1538301 Isn't it already a form submission?

Comment: @Benjamin right now you have a <form> with no "submit" type button and no JS that submits it via the DOM. There's no way this form will be "submitted" using native HTML5 semantics. A form submission would take you from one URL to another (typically), during that page navigation, a <form> submission can send data to the next page; if you use GET it will send the data as query parameters (i.e. in your case, it would redirect to a URL like: `/same-webpage.html?Defender=true&3+Point+Scorer=true`; you'd then use JS to get the query parameters in `same-webpage.html` and then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there should not be same ID for multiple element. Make sure that the "skill" will be different for every element. Also add a value property to every checkbox.
You can try like this

```js
var arr = [];

function myFunction() {
  console.clear()
  var chkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("anyclass"); // get all check box array
  for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (chkBoxes[i].checked) { // check if checked
      arr.push(chkBoxes[i].value);
    }
  }

  arr.forEach(item => console.log(item));
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="val1" class="anyclass" />
<input type="checkbox" value="val2" class="anyclass" />
<input type="checkbox" value="val3" class="anyclass" />
<input type="checkbox" value="val4" class="anyclass" />
<p id="demo">ddd</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Now you can store this array in local storage and use it in other page where necessary.